# How to add a sequentially incrementing column to spark data frame that starts at n (PySpark)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, auto-increment

I have a dataframe that has values such as

```
 -------------
| col1 | col2 |       
 -------------
| a    |   2  |
| b    |   3  |
| c    |   4  |
| d    |   5  |
 -------------
```

I want to create a third column that has an auto incrementing value starting from a specified number.

Suppose I want the number to start from 5, then the expected output should be

```
 --------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 | 
|--------------------|
| a    |   2  | 5    |
| b    |   3  | 6    |
| c    |   4  | 7    |
| d    |   5  | 8    |
 --------------------
```

I have tried `monotonically_increasing_id()` but that does not give sequential numbers due to partitioning and it also does not have the feature to start at a specified number.

I am using Spark 2.4.5 and Pyspark (python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use window function `row_number` with `orderby()`(for sorting globally) clause and add `4` to start the sequence from `5`

> **In Pyspark:**

**`Using row_number():`**

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df=spark.createDataFrame([('a',2),('b',3),('c',4),('d',5)],['col1','col2']).repartition(4)
w=Window.orderBy('col2')
df.withColumn("col3",row_number().over(w) + 4).show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   a|   2|   5|
#|   b|   3|   6|
#|   c|   4|   7|
#|   d|   5|   8|
#+----+----+----+
```

> **In Scala:**

```
val w = Window.orderBy("col2")
df.withColumn("col3", row_number().over(w) + 4).show()

//+----+----+----+
//|col1|col2|col3|
//+----+----+----+
//|   a|   2|   5|
//|   b|   3|   6|
//|   c|   4|   7|
//|   d|   5|   8|
//+----+----+----+
```